# Cant unpublish pages access denied error

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I get the sharepoint access denied page when I try to use the unpublish option on a list item in the pages library.

We are using approval workflow and publishing, as well as versioning on the pages library.

If I navigate to the version history page, the unpublish version works correctly.

Can anyone advise on this?

All the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [code solutions for that problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/074e8139-ed56-40a6-8efd-339828aeb719), if you are able customize your application.

Comment: This is a definate bug with the product, without using workflows it works fine. I had a similar problem with cancel approval when the user is not a site owner, if their permissions level does not allow this to happen in code, then the UI fails.